# While using Flink Stateful functions is there a simple approach to handle multiple message types from the same kafka ingress topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, stateful, flink-statefun

I have multiple message types being consumed from the same Kafka topic ingress. While I can extend the message types to a 'wrapper' super class then downcast them after they are de-serialized, this does not seem like a good option. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: what SDK are you using? if you are using remote functions you can simple get the raw bytes of a message and handle serialization in your functions. If you are using the embedded SDK, you can still achieve that by using a payload (for example Protobuf Any)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion Igal. Will try the protobuf any option